# Prompt/Blank option for select w/ collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= f.select(:id, User.all.collect{|p| [p.name, p.id]}, {}, html_options = { :style=>'border-radius: 0px;' }) %>
```

I'm using the above statement to get a select box populated with users. I want to include either a blank or, preferably, prompt box selected by default. I'm using Rails 3.2, and I've yet to find a solution that works for me. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (updated):

```
<%= f.select(:id, User.all.collect{|p| [p.name, p.id]}, { include_blank: 'Prompt text...'}, html_options: { :style=>'border-radius: 0px;' }) %>
```

Comment: What is it missing?  You do get the prompt box in the select option don't you?

Comment: Throws a SyntaxError: /.../app/views/postings/edit.html.erb:56: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting tASSOC
...style=>'border-radius: 0px;' }) );@output_buffer.safe_concat...

Comment: Updated answer, try that now.  The `html_options =`, it's complaining because it expects hash notation as other options.

Comment: Still no luck, the syntax error is gone, but the prompt text isn't displaying.

Comment: The last update I could suggest is replacing `prompt: 'Prompt text...'` with `{ include_blank: 'Prompt text...'` }` based on this: [`.prompt doesn't work`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select#81--prompt-doesn-t-work).

Comment: That's what I ended up going with; hacky and stupid, but it works.